# New Editor make the toolbar always on top

Tags: interface

In 2.8 when I create a new Editor the toolbar is always created on top. Can we change that?
I need to put it on bottom every time....manually...
Or maybe a script that can do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this?

[image: Flip]

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't resolve the problem, as when I change the editor, for example in Timeline, the toolbar will be still on top of the screen. And also the Blender doesn't remind how was the bar on the previous editor when I come back.
But thanks for the help anyway,

Comment: Blender will remember your settings if you 'save start-up file'. See the last step in the video. Also make sure you press enter when it asks 'save startup file?' after clicking the option. I don't know of an option to set the tool-bar at the top for all views. Maybe you can set it once and save startup file, so that you get the settings you want in the next session.